# Continuous Testing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, junit

This is my first time making an Android application after I started to do NodeJS. My last Android application was when Android 7 and Eclipse, and it way past. Going back to develop for Android need a lot of adjustment, and it was not smooth and butter.

Having spoiled with something like nodemon or ng-serve, which do continuous testing automatically after every code change, I am trying to look something similar in Android Studio and Kotlin. That way I could experiment, test, do trial and error, or anything in Kotlin, and know the result immediately without waiting a few seconds for build and run. That could cut my learning time by a lot. Type the code and see the result immediately a the bottom of the screen.

Is that possible in Android Studio? Any plugin I have to install? Or any tutorial I need to follow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android Instant Run to reflect immediate changes to your app without completely restarting the entire app, also there is an option where you can view your App Layout side by side with your code using Android Studio Live Layout Preview. Some other methods can be using CodeWithMe to achieve faster deployment of the app and instant feedback (It is a Third Party tool).

Comment: Yeah. I see that side by side layout. But my testing and codes that runs without visual were hard to see the result. Such as if I want to see what this code does and does not, and if my code passed the test, and so on. With Nodejs, as soon as I press Ctrl-S, all consoles shows all kinds of updated stuffs. I am going to try that Android Instant Run. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: Ok, I've tried Instant Run, but I still have to press Ctrl-Shift-F10 to manually run it. And it would only run one unit test. Is there any other ideas?